# Cookie from Redirected Site

Tags: java, html, spring, redirect, cookies

From Original website redirecting to another webapplication. After logining into that webapp, needs to redirect to original site along with the Cookie set in the redirected site. I can code only on original website code. is it possible to fetch the cookie set by the redirect site ?  Consider both web apps running in same webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Not possible if applications run on different domains (no matter if same physical webserver).

**Long answer:**

Cookies are bound to the host and port of the site, that created them in the first place. Otherwise it would be a dramatic security issue, as one could just overwrite cookies of different sites.

If you want to pass over some token to a different host, you have to do this by submitting it in a hidden field of a form or by appending it to the query parameters of the URL.

In either case the destination host has to know how to read that value.

If there is a XSS vulnerability, you could use a script to set the cookie as soon as the user arrived on the destination site. In theory. However you should not attempt this, unless there is a legitimate way.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian for detailing. On couple of google searches got that Cookies will be sent to host based on the path by browser. Browser looks for path and matching cookies will be sent. Ofcourse checks expiration as well.

Answer (score 0):

Every web server keeps unique id for each client.
If your web apps in different web servers, then it is not possible.

Comment: Assume both applications are running in same web server.